# use material icons in highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I'm customizing new buttons, I want to use material-icon for the button icons:

```
options = {
  exporting: {
    enabled: true,

    buttons: {
     zoomInButton: {
       symbol: 'zoom_in',
       onclick: function () {
        this.zoom()
       }
     }
   }
}
};
```

but the symbol is a circle instead of the material one. Is it possible to add this for the button icon?

Comment: This example shows how to replace the export button; http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/buttons-contextbutton-symbol-custom/. The same should be possible to do for any other buttons that you wish to replace. That said, I am not sure what button zoom_in is so that might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SVG Renderer** is able to generate the image and append it to the zoom button.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.renderer.image('image_path', 0, 0, 25, 25).add(this.mapNavButtons[0]);
    }
  }
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/190pk1ap/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#add
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image